# What is the clean way to Implement Audit Trail in Asp.net MVC and Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, audit

I am trying to look for a more clean way to add audit trail function to an exist asp.net MVC and Web Api project which contains hundreds of `Controller` and `ApiController`.

The Audit trail log would look like below. Basically I just want to log `In what time who did what` in this function.

```
UserID

ActionTime

Controller 

Action
```

Anything I missed ? If there is . Please correct me. Thanks.

Currently I found there are some ways to make it .

1. Implement an `ActionFilterAttribute` and write my own log function in the `OnActionExecuting`, and then decorate all the actions with this attribute.
2. Implement a base `Controller` like `BaseController` for all the exist controller. And write log in the `OnActionExecuting`. Then change all the controller to inherit from `BaseController`. (If it is wrong . Please correct me . Thanks.)
3. For the `ApiController`. Implement a `DelegatingHandler` to make it.

For 1 and 2. I need change to all the exist code to make it. like change base class or decorate with new attribute. Considering in my case, This will be a hard work. Because thousands of class or methods need to be changed . I thinks it is kind of verbose. So I wondered if there is some clean way like 3 for ApiController to make it. Thanks.

Comment: I think you can do this using a combination of `ActionFilters` and `MessageHandlers`. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/12300537/325521 and http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/581908/CreatingplusAdvancedplusAuditplusTrailsplususingpl source code on github => https://github.com/Rionmonster/Advanced-Auditing

Comment: Is there anything like DelegatingHandler in the MVC Controller? so I don't need to change the exist code. Sorry. I am lazy man..Thanks.

Comment: and I know the ways you mentioned is good work around. But I just try to figure out a better or Lazy way. Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain how your question (and possible solution) is any different to others, where the answer was to use an [AOP toolset like PostSharp](https://www.postsharp.net/aspects)?

Comment: @slugster please help to review my comment in the Mukus answer. Thanks.

Comment: These two libraries implements action filters to generate audit trails for both WebAPI and MVC, for NET Core and NET 4.5. You can take a look at the code on [Audit.MVC](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET/tree/master/src/Audit.Mvc#auditmvc) and [Audit.WebApi](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET/tree/master/src/Audit.WebApi#auditwebapi)

Comment: It is a really nice library. They work very well. Thank to your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using a DI container? If you are or want to use a DI container, that could intercept all requests to the controllers. That way you don't change  codes in hundreds of controllers, albeit simple change.

Here's Castle Windsor DI.

```
public class WindsorControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
{
private readonly IKernel _kernel;

public WindsorControllerFactory(IKernel kernel)
{
    _kernel = kernel;
}

public override void ReleaseController(IController controller)
{
    _kernel.ReleaseComponent(controller);
}

protected override IController GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
{
    if (controllerType == null)
    {
        throw new HttpException(404, string.Format("The controller for path '{0}' could not be found.", requestContext.HttpContext.Request.Path));
    }

    return (IController)_kernel.Resolve(controllerType);
}
}
```

Have a look at [the examples on this site](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/README.md) if you intended to use it. I am sure there is a way to use it for both Web API and MVC controllers.

Comment: +1 Yeah. That is a good idea to make it .I already have `Unity` in my project. But ... All the controllers are not created from the factory in the run time.  I am afraid that the Intercept can not be working ...I need to do some research. Thanks.

Comment: I worried about another problem which is using Unity interception will lose the context of the MVC controller and WebApiController.. I mean It will not easy to retrieve the information like route data . request and response etc. Right ?

Comment: Can this help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19794438/unity-dependency-injection-with-global-web-api-filter-attribute

Comment: em....Need more time to read. But It should be an efficient way to Audit both MVC and WebApi. Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

I find that using global action filters is the best way to handle cross-cutting/aspect-oriented concerns such as this.

Note that this code is not tested.

```
public class AuditFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        var userName = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
        var time = DateTime.Now.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        var controllerName = actionContext.ControllerContext.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName;
        var actionName = actionContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName

        Logger.Log(string.Format("user: {0}, date: {1}, controller {2}, action {3}", userName, time, controllerName, actionName));
    }
}
```

And somewhere in your application startup pipeline, register the filter globally:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Filters.Add(new AuditFilter());
```

Comment: This is the simplest way to intercept in the MVC. Thanks you man.

Comment: Actually this one is for Web API. You would have to create a separate one for MVC that would look basically the same except you would get the Controller and Action name from the RouteData and register the filter using  GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(...).

Comment: I understand that this solution would help logging request part of it. Lets say if I want to extend this to also capture success/failure after actual controller method is executed and also log the same - any suggestions for this?